# How to mount LUKS encrypted file?

Tags: mount, encryption, lvm, luks

I have a file (about 13GB).

When I execute the command `file "filename"` in terminal,
It shows `tails_filesystem: LUKS encrypted file, ver 1 [aes, xts-plain64, sha1] UUID : blahblah`

And, when I mount in FTK imager for viewing filesystem,
It shows `Unrecognized file system [unknown]`

I know LUKS passphrase for this file dump.

But I don't know how to mount this file dump for analysing.

Google contains only a few methods of encrypting volume by dm-crypt... :'(
(In addition, I tried to analyse with freeOTFE & librecrypt. This failed.)

How can I see files in LUKS encrypted filesystem dump??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Be sure dm-crypt kernel module is loaded.

```
modprobe dm-crypt
```

Then I would suggest:

```
cryptsetup open --type luks /path/to/dump desired-name
```

This should create a device /dev/mapper/desired-name which you can then mount as used to.

```
mount /dev/mapper/desired-name /mnt
```

I'm not sure if this works for a dump. But it's quite possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can mount it and start to analysis. Thanks very much!!! :)

Comment: @Jensen Could you be so kind to marks this answer as correct and vote for it?