# Reading external disk with LUKS/LVM2 partitions

Tags: partitioning, ssd, luks

I have Ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop. My desktop has Ubuntu 18.04. I have removed the SSD from my desktop and attached it to my laptop via USB C. I want to copy some files from this external SSD to the laptop. However, the external SSD was set up with LUKS/LVM2 and I cannot see the directories in Nautilus.

What do you suggest?

[Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIPxs.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount LUKS encrypted file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835525/how-to-mount-luks-encrypted-file)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out how to mount the LVM2 partition from [Cyberbitz](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-an-lvm-volume-partition-command/) for anyone else in the same pickle.